# Why is the product of the reaction between iron and steam is iron (II, III) oxide and not iron (II) oxide or iron (III) oxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, crystal-structure, reaction-control

The reaction between Iron and steam in my textbook is given as this:

$$\ce{3Fe + 4H_2O <=> Fe_3O4 + H_2} $$

My question is why these following reactions are not possible or do not happen.
$$\ce{Fe + H_2O <=> FeO + H2}$$ 
$$\ce{2Fe + 3H_2O <=> Fe_2O_3 + 3H2}$$

I mean, how do the atoms *know* to form iron (II,III) oxide instead of Iron (II) oxide or iron (III) oxide in this reaction?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\ce{Fe3O4}$ is basically just an equimolar mixture of $\ce{FeO}$ and $\ce{Fe2O3}$. So, in that way, both of the reactions that you mentioned *do* infact happen, and the result is what was mentioned in your textbook.